# ¿Cómo encontrar los valores en que se diferencian dos series de dos DataFrame en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero realizar en python el siguiente proceso que en RStudio es muy sencillo con la función `setdiff()`

```
library(tidyverse)

# 1| data.frame sobre población
pop <- structure(list(country = c("Afghanistan", "Angola", "Albania", 
                                  "Andorra", "United Arab Emirates", 
                                  'Canada', 'United States'),
                      `2021` = c("40.8M", "35M", "2.87M", "77.5k", "10.1M", "30.2M", "50.6M"), 
                      `2022` = c("41.7M", "36.1M", "2.86M", "77.6k", "10.2M", "30.6M","51.7M")), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# data.frame sobre ingresos
inc <- structure(list(country = c("Afghanistan", "Angola", "Albania", 
                                  "Andorra", "United Arab Emirates"), 
                      `2021` = c("1990", "5980", "14.7k", "56.5k", "65.2k"), 
                      `2022` = c("2040", "6000", "15.1k", "56.9k", "66.3k")), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

setdiff(pop$country, inc$country)
```

El resultado de la función `setdiff()`, arroja: "Canada" "United States"

¿Cómo puedo realizar este mismo proceso pero en python?

Comment: Que intentaste/investigaste para lograr eso? Recuerda que para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida tendría que tener una demostración de que sos parte del esfuerzo por responderla.

Comment: Descargué datos de esas dos variables desde la web de gapminder, y la base de datos de población difiere en esos dos países con la de ingresos. Puede encontrar la diferencia muy fácil en R, pero estoy aprendiendo python y quisiera saber cómo lograr lo mismo en ese lenguaje. No se lo copié a alguien o por el estilo si es a lo que se refiere.

Comment: Que bien que hayas puesto esfuerzo en escribir el código por tu cuenta! Peeero no me refería a eso, me refería a algún esfuerzo por responder la pregunta "¿Cómo puedo realizar este mismo proceso pero en python?", sea por ejemplo, buscar en Google.

Comment: ahh ok, sí, claro, he googleado y leído sobre funciones como difference, equals, y otras más, pero muchas solo hacen el trabajo para listas y no para series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No está muy claro por qué hablas de dataframes, pues en el fondo lo que buscas es encontrar la diferencia entre dos listas (o series de valores).

Así que de momento olvidémonos de dataframes, puesto que además el código que muestras ni siquiera es Python y por tanto no se puede saber qué estructura tendrían esos dataframes tuyos si usaras pandas.

Vamos a suponer que de algún modo consigues tener en un par de listas los países cuya diferencia quieres obtener:

```
paises_pop = ["Afghanistan", "Angola", "Albania", "Andorra", "United Arab Emirates", 'Canada', 'United States']
paises_inc = ["Afghanistan", "Angola", "Albania", "Andorra", "United Arab Emirates"]
```

En este caso encontrar la diferencia entre ambas listas es muy simple si las conviertes en conjuntos (`set()`). Puedes hacer la diferencia entre conjuntos, o bien la operación XOR (que es la diferencia entre la unión de los conjuntos menos su intersección):

```
>>> set(paises_pop) ^ set(paises_inc)
{'Canada', 'United States'}
```

En este caso la diferencia (`set(paises_pop) - set(paises_inc)`) te daría el mismo resultado, pero creo que XOR es más genérico pues la diferencia sólo te daría los países que estuvieran en el primer conjunto y no en el segundo, pero no te daría los que estuvieran en el segundo y no en el primero, mientras que XOR te da todos los que están en un conjunto pero no en el otro.

Aunque esta respuesta se ejemplifica sobre un par de listas, en realidad funciona sobre cualquier tipo de iterable, por lo que son válidas también series Pandas. Por ejemplo, si se tuvieran dos dataframes `df1` y `df2` y se quisieran comparar sus columnas "country":

```
>>> set(df1.country) ^ set(df2.country)
```

Comment: Lo siento, es que traté de hacer sencillo el ejemplo para encontrar una solución, pero veo que no fue así. Es que descargué dos bases de datos en formato wide desde gapminder (uno de ingresos y otro de población), y tienen dos observaciones de diferencia, entonces encontrar los valores en que difireren para la calumna en particular (country) fue fácil en R, pero en python no sé cómo hacerlo, y soy nuevo en el segundo lenguaje.

Comment: Pero cuando dices que has descargado esas bases de datos ¿lo has hecho en R o en Python? Si lo has hecho en Python muestra por favor el código que crea los dataframes, para que la respuesta pueda ajustarse a tu problema. Si la descarga la has hecho en R me temo que la pregunta es demasiado amplia, pues no sólo estarías preguntando por cómo encontrar la diferencia entre dos series, sino cómo crear también los dataframes y eso a la vista de tu código en R no te lo podría responder, pues no entiendo R.

Comment: están en formato xlsx, en los dos lenguajes los importe haciendo uso de read_excel() en R, y pd.read_excel() en python

Comment: Ok, pues muestra entonces el fragmento de código que lee el xlsx a un dataframe y que después haga `print(df)` para mostrar también el resultado de ese print. Así podré entender la estructura del dataframe

Comment: muy agradecido por su respuesta, me sirvió

Comment: también sirve para series como él dijo

Comment: @DanteS. Hecho! Borro el comentario entonces